# RabbitMQ: How to delete/move messages in queue from curl

Tags: curl, rabbitmq, rabbitmq-exchange, rabbitmqctl

I've multiple RabbitMQ Servers.

I need an interface(with JSP) where i can manage(delete queues/exchanges/messages) of all these servers .

Internally I'll call the curl commands to do the operations.

Example: To create queue

```
curl -i -u test:test -H "content-type:application/json" \
    -XPUT -d'{"type":"direct","durable":true}' \
    http://192.168.0.30:15672/api/queues/%2f/myQueue
```

How can i delete/move messages in a queue with curl?

Comment: Probably same question as here: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/rabbitmq-users/IS-3v4qNduw/oPseA7VxEgAJ with an answer on our mailing list

Comment: @old_sound. Yes.. It is the same question and is answered over there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer for my question is found at

https://groups.google.com/d/msg/rabbitmq-users/IS-3v4qNduw/oPseA7VxEgAJ

Comment: Quoting the hint provided in the mailing list below - "Perhaps you should use a dynamic shovel, which you can establish via the http API."

Answer (score 2):

a shovel created with a curl will do the work :

```
curl 
-u  "user:password" 
-vvv 'http://localhost:15672/api/parameters/shovel/%2Foms/Move%20from%20sourceQueue' 
-X PUT 
-H 'content-type: application/json' 
--data-binary '
{
    "component": "shovel",
    "vhost": "/vhost",
    "name": "Move from sourceQueue",
    "value": {
        "src-uri": "amqp:///%2Fvhost",
        "src-queue": "sourceQueue",
        "src-protocol": "amqp091",
        "src-prefetch-count": 1000,
        "src-delete-after": "queue-length",
        "dest-protocol": "amqp091",
        "dest-uri": "amqp:///%2Fvhost",
        "dest-add-forward-headers": false,
        "ack-mode": "on-confirm",
        "dest-queue": "destQueue"
    }
}
' --compressed
```

Comment: I had to put the URL to the end, on MacOS.

Answer (score 0):

RabbitMQ does not have the concept of directly deleting messages off of a queue. There are many different ways to do the equivalent of "deleting" or "moving" messages from a queue when using RabbitMQ.  Each of these options are available to you using the REST api. You can either consume messages off of a queue or you can expire messages from the queue.

Consuming messages from a queue is pretty simple, and there are examples [here.](http://hg.rabbitmq.com/rabbitmq-management/raw-file/3646dee55e02/priv/www-api/help.html)  To use expiry via Time To Live or Size of the queue you can set up a RabbitMQ policy.  The documentation for RabbitMQ policies is [here.](https://www.rabbitmq.com/parameters.html)